# GIT vs SVN : How is it different in terms of commit (in GIT) and just save the changes locally in the file (in SVN)

Tags: git, git-svn

I want to know what difference(or rather advantage) does GIT gives when doing local commits (*commit command*) as compared to just saving the changes in the working directory in SVN **when working offline (not connected to server)**

I have read that GIT gives an advantage of working offline i.e. user can perform commits locally as many times as he wants to and then when the user is connected to the server, (s)he can push the changes to remote server. I would like to know why is it advantageous if all *commit* command does is just committing to local disk which is again same as just saving your changes to the disk in SVN (when not connected with the server) and not committing to project branch.

I like GIT but I am not able to understand this difference. Please help !!

Thanks,
Nayan

Comment: +1: I struggle to understand why GIT is so popular, aside from "it's what the cool kids use".

Comment: Because it is decentralised, allows you to have version control locally as well as on a server.  You do not need to 'commit' your potentially not complete task just to ensure it is stored in version control, like you would in SVN.  Referring to Git as 'what the cool kids use' shows that you probably haven't really used much (if it all) to make a valid comparison with SVN.

Comment: I think the strongest difference is the decoupling of version control from team sharing.  Version control offers all sorts of benefits that don't necessarily include sharing with team members.  Decentralized version control allows you to share complete units of work with one another, but still save incomplete work history for yourself.  If you've ever used version control on a personal project, it's easy to see the difference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Scenario:** You download the latest code from your repository onto your laptop before going offline (say for a long airplane journey).

On the flight you make some changes - you run units tests, run the code, everything seems to be working. You make some more changes - test them, things are still working. You get really enthusiastic and make a bunch more changes with some heavy re-factoring. You test the changes - everything's broken (e.g. because you made a bad assumption somewhere).

**With SVN:** Reverting the code to a working state is going to be tricky, because you can't remember how it looked before you started all that heavy refactoring. It'll likely involve a lot of tedious diffs between the code on your laptop and the master server whenever you get network access again. Meanwhile, you are stuck.

**With Git:** Assuming you were sensible and committed your changes to your local repository each time you knew it was in a working state, rolling back to the commit before you started that refactoring work is easy. You keep your valuable work and can start going down the right path straight away. When you get network access again you can push these changes to the master branch in one go and all will be well.

Comment: +1: clear and simple. I guess you could make an SVN repo on your laptop and switch between that one and the main one, but in GIT it seems to be built in.

Comment: I know that's the usual argument but honestly how often has anyone actually done that? The SVN solution then is to `cp -R` or `robocopy /e` your working copy at the intermediate steps so you have known-good versions elsewhere on disk. You can even commit them in sequence too, although that normally involves grafting the `.svn` directories around to avoid getting conflicts on the update before commit in the second and subsequent WC copies. But it's doable without too much effort, though granted more effort than the git.

Comment: I've actually done that, though not quite as dramatically as described above. ;) I'd argue that using `cp` or `robocopy` isn't really an "SVN" solution, it's using another tool as a workaround for something SVN chooses not to handle, and as you pointed out it may require a bit of fiddling to avoid problems. The Git alternative uses less space by just storing diffs of changed files rather than duplicating the entire project. Also it keeps all the data nicely organised in a logical location rather than in arbitrary other folders on the disk.

Answer (score 5):

A commit isn't saving a file to disk, you don't need any version control software for this.

Committing in version control means saving a new increment in file's history, so you can log and recover different states. And then Git differs with SVN because this step is performed locally, without any remote server communication, to the difference of SVN.

When using SVN in offline mode, you can't issue any commit, so the history of your work isn't logged, although it saved to local disk. It is not the case with Git.

Answer (score 2):

By committing you are storing your code in version control, not just saving to disk.  This allows you to really manage your code and project as it grows.

Git also allows use to create task-branches throughout your project lifecycle, enabling you to keep a master code base that is always working (on a server), a master code base that works locally and then you can branch this master code as you implement new features and swap between all of these.  Without having to 'commit' code to a server like you do in SVN to ensure it is safe.

By committing and branching locally, this enables you to work effectively and safely offline. SVN requires you to commit those changes to a server just to make sure they are safe.  Git is decentralised.

I believe you'll answer your own question as you investigate the features of Git and use it more.  Then if you go back to SVN, you'll wish you were on Git ;)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head:

1. Offline version control (no need to communicate with remote repository for saving work progress).
2. Much easier branching and merging for task switching.
3. Much more sophisticated merging... reduces merge pain.
4. Track work progress without forcing the rest of your team to accept incomplete state.